# cURL is always fetching cached copy

Tags: caching, curl, ssh, centos6

My script usually takes ~4min to finish, but whenever I execute cURL in SSH, it shows output immediately, which is an old attempt.
This is happening in SSH & `crontab` only, while `wget` and using my browser always get fresh content.
I tried adding `'Cache-Control: no-cache'` parameter to the command, but didn't help.

```
root@server [~]# /usr/bin/curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' http://full-path/curl
```

What else should I try?

Comment: Maybe it's `crontab` that maintains a cache... look [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/498210/does-cron-maintain-an-in-memory-directory-cache). There are other questions concerning this, though, so you may as well just search Google for "crontab cache."

Comment: It's not only `crontab`, it's happening also when I just use `curl` command in the terminal outside `crontab`. It immediately outputs an old copy.

Answer (score 0):

You could append ?xyz=`1469279729` to get unique url strings and avoid caching.  But it's unlikely to be curl that is caching results, either a proxy/server returning stale data, or some alias to curl with local caching.

Comment: My actual URL has `?corn` so I appended `&xyz=123` but this didn't make any help. As far as I remember I have `varnish` as caching server, I am not sure, I'll try to figure it out. Thanks for your input.